# Is there a setting to force an error when asigning a varchar longer than a variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to get an error when assigning a longer varchar to a variable and no silent truncation. Are there any settings?

This truncates silently:

```
declare @code varchar(10)
set @code = 'This is too long'
select @code
```

Inserting a varchar into a smaller Table column

```
create table test (col1 varchar(10));
insert into test values ('This is too long');
```

yields an error:

```
Meldung 8152, Ebene 16, Status 14, Zeile 2
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: I wish there were. This bites me in the ass all the time, particularly with stored procedure parameters.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628140/sql-server-silently-truncates-varchars-in-stored-procedures

Comment: unfortunately the jist is, there's no automated way to  check for this.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for this problem:

```
declare @code varchar(10)
declare @input VARCHAR(200)
set @input = 'Set your input code here'

IF(LEN(@input) <= 10) -- make sure this number is same as length of 'code' variable
    SET @code = @input

ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Inputted string is too long for the variable.'
    RETURN
END

select @code
```

Comment: I do not want to change other peoples scripts, I want to to force the system to trow errors when I have to run the script.

Comment: Silent truncation doesn't raise a SQL Server error (hence the name) so you will have to do the error handling within the code.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to 
1  change all incoming parameters to be varchar(max) 
2. have sp private variable of the correct datalength (simply copy and paste all in parameters and add "int" at the end 
3. declare a table variable with the column names the same as variable names 
4. Insert into the table a row where each variable goes into the column with the same name 
5. Select from the table into internal variables

This way your modifications to the existing code are going to be very minimal like in the sample below 
**Original code** 
create procedure spTest 
( 
  @p1 varchar(2), 
  @p2 varchar(3) 
) 
**new code** 
create procedure spTest 
( 
  @p1 varchar(max), 
  @p2 varchar(max) 
) 
declare @p1Int varchar(2),  @p2Int varchar(3) 
declare @test table (p1 varchar(2), p2 varchar(3) 
insert into @test (p1,p2) varlues (@p1, @p2) 
select @p1Int=p1, @p2Int=p2 from @test 
*Note that if the length of the incoming parameters is going to be greater than the limit instead of silently chopping off the string SQL Server will throw off an error.*

Comment: Beware there is a [slight performance penalty](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/) to using the `MAX` datatypes.